# Is there a way to optimize this RedisGraph query?

Tags: redis, arangodb, redisgraph

I have this query "Get Recommended/Similar Products" on both RedisGraph and ArangoDB, and RedisGraph is showing significant slow execution time in comparison to ArangoDB. Although RedisGraph benchmarks show that it should have a better performance than other graph databases.

Ref: https://redis.com/blog/new-redisgraph-1-0-achieves-600x-faster-performance-graph-databases/

The query fetches what other products users who have purchased this specific product (id: 123) have also purchased, while filtering out the current user's (id: 321) purchases, and also while ordering the result by the products that occurred the most.

Here is the RedisGraph query I used:

```
MATCH (:product {id: 123})<-[:purchased]-(:user)-[r:purchased]->(p:product)
WHERE NOT (:user {id: 321})-[:purchased]->(p)
WITH p, COUNT(r) as occurrence
WHERE occurrence > 9
RETURN p.id as product_id, occurrence
ORDER BY occurrence DESC
LIMIT 5
```

It had an execution time of 6177.225 ms.

While the ArangoDB query looks like this:

```
LET userPurchases = (FOR purchase IN OUTBOUND 'users/321' purchases RETURN purchase._id)
FOR product,purchase IN 2..2 ANY 'products/123' purchases
FILTER purchase._to NOT IN userPurchases
COLLECT product_id = product._key WITH COUNT INTO occurrence
FILTER occurrence > 9
SORT occurrence DESC
LIMIT 5
RETURN {product_id, occurrence}
```

And it had an execution time of only 33.256 ms.

**Is there a way to optimize my Redisgraph query any further to make it match/exceed ArangoDB's performance?**

More information regarding the schemas of both databases:

RedisGraph

| Collection | Type | Indices | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| user | node | id | 2 M |
| product | node | id | 177 K |
| purchased | relation |  | 400 K |

ArangoDB

| Collection | Type | Indices | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| users | document | _key | 6.7 M |
| products | document | _key | 135 K |
| purchases | edge | _from, _to | 420 K |